# How does a Java compiler statically check if something is able to be casted?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

Many java compilers give you a warning or error that some A cannot be casted to some B when you are trying to compile.

Where can I find information about how some java compilers check this during compile time?

Comment: The compiler understands types and type hierarchies. So it's able to detect two unrelated classes.

Comment: Right. But I would like to see concrete implementation details on it. Source code would be most reliable. For example, if perhaps someone can direct me to where in the Eclipse code base does this, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @itsmarziparzi [Knock yourself out](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/). If you really want to understand compilation/type checking, read the dragon book.

Comment: OpenJDK is open source... So go check it out. You'll probably benefit from reading through the specification as well.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch What's the dragon book

Comment: [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](https://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Tools-2nd/dp/0321486811) by Aho, et al.

Comment: Here's the concrete implementation in OpenJDK: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/d5c43e9f08fb/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Types.java#l1620

Comment: Regarding the Dragon Book, I'd recommend against it as an introduction to compiler construction (or even as a non-introduction as it's very outdated). And this question specifically isn't even addressed in it (the section on type conversions does not mention checking the validity of casts).

Comment: @sepp2k You have to [start somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23857794/2970947).